# C Interrput every rsing edge 100kHz

Tags: gpio, c, interrupts

i've a 100kHz signal and i want to detect every rising edge.
I'm using ISR but edge isn't detected and when detected it's 46µs after the edeg.

How to do?

[EDIT]
Here's the code with pigpio library:

```
int main (void)
{
    if (gpioInitialise() < 0)
    {
       printf("FAILED"); // pigpio initialisation failed.
    }
    else
    {
        printf("OK");// pigpio initialised okay.
    }
    gpioSetMode (RSPI_DATA, PI_INPUT) ;
    gpioSetMode (RSPI_LATCH, PI_INPUT) ;
    gpioSetMode (RSPI_CLK, PI_INPUT) ;
    gpioSetMode (RSPI_A, PI_OUTPUT) ;
    gpioWrite(RSPI_A,0);
    printf("bb\n");
     while(1)
    {
        if (gpioRead(RSPI_LATCH)==1)
        {
            if (gpioRead(RSPI_LATCH)==0)                                    // FALLING
            {
                gpioWrite(RSPI_A,1);
                cpt_nb_clk=0;
                gpioWrite(RSPI_A,0);
            }
        }
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

And here's the result:

[image]

Comment: 46us is pretty reasonable nom rt kernel latency. Your problem is why RTOS is fundamentally different from Linux

Comment: Looks like you're trying to implement an SPI slave on the Pi?

Comment: @RogerJones If it is a SPI slave I would expect no joy on the Pi with Linux unless the speed is about 1000 bps.  No way a response can be guaranteed to an external event in a very short time scale.

Comment: @joan Hence the question, if that's what OP is trying to do then I was going to suggest using some intermediate hardware to act like a shift register and buffer the data for the Pi to read later. Feels like the given code fragment is a first stab at detecting the /CS or /SS edge as a prelude to clocking the data in but the OS is already getting in the way.

Answer (score 0):

[pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) will detect the edge.

I'm fairly sure this will be of no use as your actual problem is probably something else.

To see the edges try [piscope](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html) or [monitor.py](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_monitor_py).

Comment: I've used the pigio library, but no more results...

Comment: @morbak You need to edit your question and explain what task you are trying to achieve.  At the moment we don't know what you are trying to do so can not offer a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try not to use an ISR for these problems. Its likely to miss an edge.
You need run a loop at these speeds. **This will make usage of a complete cpu-core.**

```
bool isOn = gpioRead(RSPI_LATCH,0);
bool isOn_t = isOn;
while(true){
  isOn_t = gpioRead(RSPI_LATCH,0);
  if(isOn && !isOn_t ){gpioWrite(RSPI_A,0);}
  else if(!isOn && isOn_t){gpioWrite(RSPI_A,1);}
  isOn=isOn_t;
}
```

Also gpioWrite is not too fast. Maybe you checkout chrono.

```
#include <chrono>

std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t1 = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::microseconds>(t1 - std::chrono::steady_clock::now()).count(); //also try nanoseconds
```